# Use Jquery to click a hidden file upload button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, file-upload, click

I have a hidden file upload as it looks really bad, I have displayed a nicer looking button and would like it to click the hidden file upload when its clicked.

```
function ClickUpload() {
    $("#FileUpload").trigger('click');
}

<div id="MyUpload">
    <span id="FileName">Choose File</span>
    <input id="uploadButton" type="button" value="Upload" onclick="ClickUpload()"> 
</div>
<div id="hideUglyUpload">
    <input type="file" name="FileUpload" id="FileUpload"/>
</div>
```

So far i can move into the function ClickUpload() but it just passes through the click without the file selection window popup.

Comment: it works for me http://jsfiddle.net/uAFY6/2/

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is on the same line as @A.Wolff 's comment... Perhaps some browsers will only initiate the file dialog when it is triggered by a user initiated event. Your `trigger` function is not user initiated so the browser might be blocking it.

Comment: @Lix AFAIK, older browser (chrome version?) doesn't allow it on hidden input, input needs to be put outside viewport. But as i can test it, now it works on chrome

Comment: When using `.triggerhandler()` you can check weather the click was triggered and if not, to display a normal `input type=file`: http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/

Comment: i have two project, in one of them i did this `$('#fakeFileButton').on('click', function () {$('#file').click();return false;});` ,and in other one i did this `$clone.find("#fake_file_button_sample").first().attr({'name': function (_, id) { return 'FakeFileButton[' + $$fileUploadIndex + ']' },
'id': function (_, id) { return 'FakeFileButton_' + $$fileUploadIndex + '_' },'value': ''}).on('click', function () {var self = $(this);var id = GetLastObjectIndexFromAString(self);$('#file_' + id + '_').click();return false;});`, but this doesn't work on second one. though they are identical :'(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange that it doesn't work. Try

```
<input id="uploadButton" type="button" value="Upload" onclick='$("#FileUpload").click()'>
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and the OP's method?

Comment: I do the same code and write ajax method in the upload click.but here the function working two times.Have any solution?

Answer (score 5):

I prefer not to have inline JS function calls in markup ... so a little change...

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#uploadButton').on('click',function(evt){
         evt.preventDefault();
         $('#FileUpload').trigger('click');
     });
  });

<div id="MyUpload">
    <span id="FileName">Choose File</span>
    <input id="uploadButton" type="button" value="Upload"> 
</div>
<div id="hideUglyUpload">
    <input type="file" name="FileUpload" id="FileUpload"/>
</div>
```